# How to read variables line by line from text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Updated based on comments

I have a txt file that has a list of variables (delimiter can be anything - I am using comma for illustration)

```
URL, filename, folder
URL, filename, folder  
URL, filename, folder
```

I have some code that processes the variables URL, filename and folder and writes to a database. I want to loop through each line and process the variables as I go. So for example

```
read variables URL, filename, folder in first line 
process
read variables URL, filename, folder in second line 
process
etc
```

There seems to be plenty of examples to read and display the line items in a txt file, but I am struggling to find an example that reads a line, processes some code using those variables in the line, and then looping to the next line.

Updated with code based on answer below

```
with open(r"F:\Python\test.txt", "r") as inputfile:
for line in inputfile:
    URL, filename, folder = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
 <rest of code>
```

Script runs using variables from line 1 of the text file but does not loop to line 2 and process the second (or third etc) set of variables.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? i.e. input, desired output, etc. I'm confused what you mean by "variables". Normally files are taken as strings, so do you mean `'A', 'B', 'C'`? Or are they standing in for the actual values, like `a, b, c = parse(line)`, where `parse` is a function to extract the values? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the structure you put forth for each line: `URL, filename, folder`, you can grab all 3 variables in one go as such:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        url, filename, folder = line.rstrip('\n').split(', ')
        db.insert(url, filename, folder) # Or other command as needed
```

Note that you are splitting on a comma plus a space with `line.split(', ')`, as your input file separates fields with a comma plus a space. If it is truly just comma-delimited, you can take the space out of the `split` function call.

Comment: Great! So is working for the first line and output is as expected, but it is not looping to the second. I am obviously missing something very simple....

Comment: Is your input file a normal text file? Are you using the exact code I wrote above? If not please show your code. I just used this code with a print() instead of the db.insert statement and all lines were printed.

Comment: Input file is standard txt file. Code has been updated in my question above. Print shows first line of variables so assume reads correctly.

Comment: It looks like you haven't indented the `for` loop to be within the `with` file context. So indent the lines under the `with` and you should be good. Remember that python uses indentation to indicate scope!

Answer (score 0):

First I'm going to assume that what you mean by "variables" is the text inside the file, separated by commas. if that's the case then this should work:

```
with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in line.split(','):
            # do something with each item here
```

keep in mind that the items will be strings

UPDATED to reflect the change in your example file

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everybodies assistance. Based on Sam and Tim codes I resolved the problem

```
def code():

with open(r"F:\Python\test.txt", "r") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        URL, filename, folder = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        code()
```